# Replace null values with another column in another table in SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite

Does anyone nows how to replace null values with another column in another table in SQLite

say this select statement

```
SELECT t1._id , t1.name , t2.img FROM
t1 JOIN t2 on (t1._id = t2._id);
```

if `t1._id == null` i want to return `t2._id` in that column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see this:
http://sqlite.awardspace.info/syntax/sqlitepg09.htm

What you want is a case statement

```
SELECT case when t1._id is null then t2._id else t1._id end as id, t1.name , t2.img FROM
t1 JOIN t2 on (t1._id = t2._id);
```